# select top records later records

Tags: sql, select

i want to select top 500 records later records (i.e from 501 records)  to till another 100 records.

Comment: Which kind of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 2):

To select the first 500 records after `recordId` 6742:

```
select  top 500 *
from    YourTable
where   recordId > 6742
order by
        recordId
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your engine you should check keywords `LIMIT`, `OFFSET`, `ROWCOUNT` and `TOP`.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you could do `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column LIMIT 500, 100`. There isn't any generic solution for this so it would help to know what database you're working with.